# Form submission results in a blank page no matter what pass or no pass in PHP

Tags: php, html

hello I am trying to create personal website with  login following this link https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/php-tutorial/php-login-form but all value that I submit or no value give me blank
I am using wampserver

html.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>g website</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <a href="#" class="logo">g</a>
        <nav class="navigation">
            <a href="#login">login</a>
            <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </nav>
    </header>


    <section class="main">
        <div>
            <h2>Hello I am g <br><span>computer science student</span></h2>
            <a href="#projects" class="main-btn">View my work</a>
            <div class="social-icons">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-youtube"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="cards" id="login">
        <h2 class="title">login</h2>
        <div class="login">

            <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>
            
            <div id="id01" class="modal">
              
              <form class="modal-content animate" action="login.php" method="post">
              <?php if (isset($_GET['error'])) { ?>

              <p class="error"><?php echo $_GET['error']; ?></p>

               <?php } ?>
                
                <div class="imgcontainer">
                  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
                  <img src="img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                </div>
            
                <div class="container">
                    
                  <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" >
            
                  <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" >
                    
                  <button type="submit">Login</button>
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
                  </label>
                </div>
            
                <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
                  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
                  <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            
        
                
               
            
                    
               
        </div>
    </section>
    <script>
        
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('id01');
        
        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        
        </script>
    <section class="projects" id="projects">
        <h2 class="title">Projects</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="project-card">
                <div class="project-image">
                    <img src="images/work1.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="project-info">
                    <p class="project-category">future project</p>
                    <strong class="project-title">
                        <span></span>
                        <a href="#" class="more-details">More details</a>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-card">
                <div class="project-image">
                    <img src="images/work2.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="project-info">
                    <p class="project-category">future project</p>
                    <strong class="project-title">
                        <span></span>
                        <a href="#" class="more-details">More details</a>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-card">
                <div class="project-image">
                    <img src="images/work3.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="project-info">
                    <p class="project-category">future project</p>
                    <strong class="project-title">
                        <span></span>
                        <a href="#" class="more-details">More details</a>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-card">
                <div class="project-image">
                    <img src="images/work4.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="project-info">
                    <p class="project-category">future project</p>
                    <strong class="project-title">
                        <span></span>
                        <a href="#" class="more-details">More details</a>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-card">
                <div class="project-image">
                    <img src="images/work5.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="project-info">
                    <p class="project-category">future project</p>
                    <strong class="project-title">
                        <span></span>
                        <a href="#" class="more-details">More details</a>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="project-card">
                <div class="project-image">
                    <img src="images/work6.jpg" />
                </div>
                <div class="project-info">
                    <p class="project-category">future project</p>
                    <strong class="project-title">
                        <span></span>
                        <a href="#" class="more-details">More details</a>
                    </strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="cards contact" id="contact">
        <h2 class="title">Let's work together</h2>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>Phone</h3>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <h3>Email</h3>
                    <p>@gmail.com</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="social-icons">
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

this my login page I get the value from the form but i am not sure if value are sent
I triad using echo but no value are echoed
login.php

```
<?php 
echo "This is your name: ".$name;

echo "This is your email: ".$email;
session_start(); 

include "db_conn.php";
$name = $_POST['uname'];
$email = $_POST['password'];
echo "This is your name: ".$name;

echo "This is your email: ".$email;


if (isset($_POST['uname']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    
    function validate($data){

       $data = trim($data);

       $data = stripslashes($data);

       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

       return $data;

    }

    $uname = validate($_POST['uname']);

    $pass = validate($_POST['password']);

    if (empty($uname)) {

        header("Location: index.php?error=User Name is required");

        exit();

    }else if(empty($pass)){

        header("Location: index.php?error=Password is required");

        exit();

    }else{

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$uname' AND password='$pass'";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 1) {

            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if ($row['user_name'] === $uname && $row['password'] === $pass) {

                echo "Logged in!";

                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $row['user_name'];

                $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];

                $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];

                header("Location: home.php");

                exit();

            }else{

                header("Location: index.php?error=Incorect User name or password");

                exit();

            }

        }else{

            header("Location: index.php?error=Incorect User name or password");

            exit();

        }

    }

}else{
    

    header("Location: index.php");

    exit();

}
```

Comment: `isset` will take multiple parameters and will return `false` if any of them fail the test - use that to test required POST variables in on go. You are storing passwords in plain text rather than as hashes. Your sql is wide open to sql injection - **always** use prepared statements when working with user supplied data

Comment: Blank page usually is a result of the exception in the code execution (it's also very common to get it as a syntax error), try enabling error display (https://kagi.com/search?q=php+show+exceptions+in+the+response+page&r=no_region&sh=0Mddl_omCwUrjR5FXg4fCw) and update your questions with more details.

Comment: FWIW your `validate` function is complete nonsense and will harm your data instead of helping. It's a variant of a sadly all-too-common bit of cargo-cult nonsense floating around on the internet. Ask yourself what you think it's achieving, and why. `if ($row['user_name'] === $uname && $row['password'] === $pass)` is also nonsensically pointless....your SQL query already tests both of those things!

Comment: **Warning**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. It is not generally a suitable topic for an inexperienced or beginner programmer. Any [modern development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. I recommend focusing your time on learning PHP and adding genuine value to your application with new features, not something you can re-use a (reliable, well-made) product for.

Comment: ...even if this is just a student project or whatever, there's still no point in learning how to do things the wrong way (e.g. using vulnerable and unreliable SQL techniques instead of prepared statements with parameters)

Comment: Sadly that tutorial you're following should never be anywhere near any kind of tutorial or guidance site. I've no idea who thought it was a valid or useful thing to paste online. It's full of insecure rubbish and poor security practices. You can't learn anything good from it. If you insist on building your own login module, at least follow something half-decent such as [this](https://codeshack.io/secure-login-system-php-mysql/). And read https://phpdelusions.net for some really solid advice on PHP more widely (written by one of the top-rated contributors on this site (not me!)).

Comment: It is a shame that the tutorial states `"Last updated on Oct 12, 2023"` and contains so many bad practises

Answer (score 0):

In your code of

```
echo "This is your name: ".$name;

echo "This is your email: ".$email;
session_start(); 

include "db_conn.php";
$name = $_POST['uname'];
$email = $_POST['password'];
echo "This is your name: ".$name;

echo "This is your email: ".$email;
```

you try to get the value of `$name` before you initialize it. For starters, let's change this code to

```
session_start(); 

$name = $_POST['uname'] ?? '';
$email = $_POST['password'] ?? '';
echo "This is your name: ".$name;

echo "This is your email: ".$email;
include "db_conn.php";
```

Now you should have something displayed as long as you passed properly `uname` and `password` values. If you still face problems, check your server logs and see what other problems you have if any.